# Evaluating Continued Product of Radicals

Tags: limits, radicals, infinite-product, nested-radicals

I am trying to find the following continued product

$y = \sqrt{p}.\sqrt{p+p.\sqrt{p}}. \sqrt{p+p.\sqrt{p+p\sqrt{p}}}...........\infty$

for $p=\frac12$

First I squared the LHS and RHS to get 
$y^2 = p.(p + p\sqrt p)(p + p\sqrt{p+p.\sqrt p})......$

Taking p common

$y^2 = p^n.(1 + \sqrt p)(1 + \sqrt{p+p.\sqrt p}).....$

As n tends to infinity $p^n$ should tend to zero for p=1/2. Hence y=0.

Is this the correct approach? Are any alternate methods possible?

Comment: $y^2 = p^2.(1+\sqrt{p})(...$ not $p^n$

Comment: After squaring I took the p from n brackets to get $p^n$

Comment: The argument is not correct.  The product after $p^n$ tends to infinity as each term approaches 2 from below as $n$ tends to infinity.  Note $\sqrt{p+p}=1$ for $p=1/2$ and therefore the individual terms in the product for y approaches 1 from below.  Hint: consider the double angle formulas for the trigonometric functions, and see if you can figure out what the limit is.  And the solution can be found by here http://www.pi314.net/eng/viete.php

Comment: @Irrational3.14: O! yes. you are in right.

Comment: @Peder: I couldn't understand what is wrong.

Comment: @Irrational Think about why this is wrong: $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } 1 =\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } x \cdot \frac{1}{x} $. Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } \frac{1}{x}=0$, the original limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }1 = 0$.

Comment: Consider your argument for this product $1=(1/2+1/2)(1/2+1/2)*...(1/2+1/2) = (1/2)^n * 2 * 2 * ... 2$.  You are arguing that because $(1/2)^n$ tends to 0 the product must be zero, but the remaining term is $2^n$.  I haven't worked it out, but I suspect your username is going to be relevant to the answer to your question...

Comment: The answer is $y=\frac{2}{\pi}$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula) for a derivation. If you're not familiar with trigonometric identities and some limits, then you may have difficulty grasping the argument.